# How to make a number stay between 0-359? Say if it goes over by 1 to 360 it restarts to 0

Tags: java, computer-science

So I want the number to stay always stay between 0 and 359 even if it goes over to 360, 361, 362, 363... etc or under to -1, -2, -3, -4.. etc whenever I call any of the methods below.
Say if it goes over to 360 I want it to change back to 0 etc and if it goes under to -1 I want it to change to 359 etc. I have this code and it works, but the problem is that if I change the decrease or increase of amount of the heading to more than 5 then I just have to keep making for else if statements. What is a better way to write the code in which it would take into account a higher increment or decrement of the heading?

```
heading = 3;
public void changeHeadingLeft() {
    heading -= 5;
    if (heading == -1) {heading = 359;}
    else if (heading == -2) {heading = 358;}
    else if (heading == -3) {heading = 357;}
    else if (heading == -4) {heading = 356;}
    else if (heading == -5) {heading = 355;}
heading = 358
public void changeHeadingRight() {
    heading += 5;
    if (heading == 360) {heading = 0;}
    else if (heading == 361) {heading = 1;}
    else if (heading == 362) {heading = 2;}
    else if (heading == 363) {heading = 3;}
    else if (heading == 364) {heading = 4;}
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This is not C++

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513765/java-how-to-define-custom-integer-based-data-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without using if and loops.

For **increment**, use:

```
(header + amt) % 360
```

For **decrement**, use:

```
(360 + header - (amt % 360)) % 360    //(amt % 360) incase amt > 360
```

---

**Example:**

Increase 5 to header:

```
(0 + 5) % 360 = 5
```

Increase 5 to header with overflow:

```
(360 + 5) % 360 = 5
```

Decrease 5 to header:

```
(360 + 100 - (5 % 360)) % 360 = 95
```

Decrease 5 to header with underflow:

```
(360 + 0 - (5 % 360)) % 360 = 355
```

Decrease 725 to header with underflow and with amt > 360:

```
(360 + 0 - (725 % 360)) % 360 = 355
```

---

You could add those as methods, then you don't have to remember when to use which. For exmaple:

```
class CircularNumber{

    private static final int BOUND = 360;
    private int header;

    public void add(int amt){
        header = (header + amt) % BOUND;
    }

    public void deduct(int amt){
        header = (360 + header - (amt % BOUND)) % BOUND;
    }
}
```

By applying modulus on the amount to deduct with 360 before deduction, there is no need to use a loop to keep on adding 360 to the header till it becomes positive.

Answer (score 4):

That's a perfect job for the modulus operator

```
heading = heading % 360;
```

This will have `heading` cycle from 0 to 359, then back to 0 again

And to handle the negative case, yes, just add 360 until  `heading` is positive.

Comment: Or `header %= 360;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (heading < 0) { heading += 360;}
```

works for heading down to -360. And similarly

```
 if (heading >= 360) { heading -= 360; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following function:

```
public static int getHeading(int val)
{
    val %= 360;
    return (val < 0)? (val+360) :val;
}
```

See it working [here in C++](https://ideone.com/MKUxws) and [here in Java](https://ideone.com/8uJBkE):

```
class Test
{
    public static int getHeading(int val)
    {
        val %= 360;
        return (val < 0)? (val+360) :val;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] vals = {-360, 360, -361, 361, -1, 1};

        for(int i = 0; i< vals.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(vals[i] +  " = " + getHeading(vals[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
-360 = 0
360 = 0
-361 = 359
361 = 1
-1 = 359
1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

for values smaller then 0

```
while(heading < 0){heading+=360;}
```

for value bigger then 360

```
while(heading >= 360){heading-=360;}
```

with the while loops it also is possible to go with values smaller then -360

Comment: Do you mean `if` instead of `while` ? There is no need to use loop for this at all.

Comment: if the values can't get smaller then -360, or bigger then 360, then yes @john's answer with the "if" instead of "while" would (maybe) be better.

Answer (score 2):

for left change:

```
heading = heading > 0 ? heading : 360 + heading
```

and for right change:

```
heading = heading < 360 ? heading : heading - 360
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
public class myClass {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
while(n < 0){n+=360;}
while(n >= 360){n-=360;}
System.out.println(" number: " + n);

    }
}
```

Comment: /* As per recent answers, their logic is perfect for what u need.If u still need a run able code, here it is. U may enter yr function to get the number instead of entering at run-time*/